# What are disadvantages of a Operating System that recognise file extensions ?

Tags: operating-systems, os-kernel, filesystems

When Operating system recognise the file types It has several advantages like 
1. avoid mistakes like trying to print a object file that produce garbage output

but I can't think about disadvantages of an OS that recognise file systems
Anybody has an idea ?

Comment: I'm not sure this is really a computer *science* question. What does the community think?

Comment: Also, displaying the contents of a file seems to be something an application would do, not an operating system.

Comment: This is a question from my CS-OS class. actually here they are mentioning about old operating systems. OSs that are recognise extensions out of the box and OSs doesn't recognise extensions. I can't imagine any disadvantage of recognising file extensions

Comment: Being included in a CS degree doesn't guarantee being on-topic here: for example, every CS degree I know of has programming courses but we don't take questions about those here.

Comment: I thought Operating System theories are related to the Computer science section. So where should i post this question ?

Comment: For now, I suggest you leave it here. I think it's borderline whether it's on-topic or not and nobody else has expressed an opinion. It might just be me being a grumpy theoretician. :-)

Comment: I agree with @DavidRicherby; this seems to be an issue of practical implementation, not concepts. That said, it *seems* to violate software engineering principles, at least separation of concerns. (I don't know that any useful OS I've used cares about semantics of file names or contents.)